# JSON parse error: Can not set com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.KioskCustomization field

Tags: android-management-api

Issue while creating Policy In Android Management API,Iam Using Spring Boot as BackEnd.

this is my request:

{
"name": "testpolicy",
"applications": [
{
"packageName": "com.adobe.reader",
"installType": "REQUIRED_FOR_SETUP",
"defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
}
],
"kioskCustomization":{
"powerButtonActions": "POWER_BUTTON_ACTIONS_UNSPECIFIED",
"systemErrorWarnings": "SYSTEM_ERROR_WARNINGS_UNSPECIFIED",
"systemNavigation": "SYSTEM_NAVIGATION_UNSPECIFIED",
"statusBar": "STATUS_BAR_UNSPECIFIED",
"deviceSettings": "DEVICE_SETTINGS_UNSPECIFIED"
},
"kioskCustomLauncherEnabled": true
}

This is my response:

JSON parse error: Can not set com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.KioskCustomization field com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.Policy.kioskCustomization to java.util.LinkedHashMap; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not set com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.KioskCustomization field com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.Policy.kioskCustomization to java.util.LinkedHashMap (through reference chain: com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.Policy["kioskCustomization"])

code written in the controller:

```
@PostMapping("/policies")
public ResponseEntity<com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.Policy> savePolicy(
        @RequestBody Policy policy, @RequestParam String enterpriseId) throws Exception {
```

}

control is not even coming inside the controller

Answer (score 0):

I tried your request in [Quickstart](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/google/android-management-api-samples/blob/master/notebooks/quickstart.ipynb) and did not encounter any error, the cause of your error may come from your implementation (Parser being used, or the format when typed) , I suggest that you try your request in quickstart to confirm that there is nothing wrong with your request.

Also you can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/management/sample-app) for a sample app that demonstrates how to provision a corporate-owned, single-use (COSU) device, and send it a reboot command. The app uses the Android Management API Java client library.